# Can I add reference of Autofac 3.* + in my own Portable Class Library?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, cross-platform, autofac, portable-class-library

I have one Application which is targeting to Windows Store App and Windows Phone App.
I use one project called DataAccess which is type of Portable Class Library now i want to add Autofac Reference to this DataAccess Class ....
Try but not succeed can any one help me to get out of this issue ?
Thank you.

Comment: How have you tried to add Autofac? With using Nuget? What error message have you got?

Comment: @nemesv : It's not Listing PCL(Portable Class Library) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Got It.
Need to remove target platform Silverlight < 5(Silver Light 4.5 +) while adding any PCL.